# TwilioRestException when sending SMS using Twilio

Tags: rest, exception, twilio, twilio-api

```
import os
from twilio.rest import Client

account_sid = 'my_account_sid' 
auth_token = 'my_auth_token' 

client = Client(account_sid, auth_token) 

def send_sms(user_code , phone_number):
    message = client.messages.create(
        body= f'Hi your verification code is {user_code}',
        from_ = '+14158557747',
        to = f'{phone_number}')
```

**# phone_number goes in with international format something like this +9779845000001**

I get following error log while running server..

```
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/verify/
Django Version: 3.1.6
Exception Type: TwilioRestException
Exception Value:    
[31m[49mHTTP Error[0m [37m[49mYour request was:[0m

[36m[49mPOST /Accounts/AC3c6c0502535317b9bb95efd43c6296d1/Messages.json[0m

[37m[49mTwilio returned the following information:[0m

[34m[49mUnable to create record: Authenticate[0m

[37m[49mMore information may be available here:[0m

[34m[49mhttps://www.twilio.com/docs/errors/20003[0m
```

**Any Help would be appreciable.**

Comment: Have you had a look at https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/errors/20003 ? You get a permission denied error. Are you sure you're passing the correct account sid and auth token? Also did you register the from number with Twilio in your account?

Comment: @yvesonline yup went through it , and rechecked the auth token , found it different. I have no clue how it happened though. And I used that very token from twilio dashboard  in script but didn't work either. I created another account now it's working fine. Thanks for suggestion !!

Comment: Glad you figured it out and it works now!

Comment: It happened because I pushed the auth token in repo , twillio detected it and changed the auth token , Please make sure that you don't push auth token in repo .

Answer (score 0):

Just see and type the Account Sid from Twilio console. While copy and paste this account sid will change. You can copy and paste token.
Make sure that 'to' number is verified if it is a trail account.